# How to get Python Object Parent?

Tags: python, class, object, parent

So, I'm trying to get the object that a custom object is 'inside' of. Here's an example.

Assume that o is an object - it doesn't matter what kind, it can just store variables.

```
o = Object()
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent = o ## This is where I fall off; I want to be able to access
                        ## the o object from within the Test object

o.test = Test()
```

So, how would I get *o* from inside of Test? I know I could write the Test function to pass it in with

```
o.test = Test(o)
```

but I'd rather do it from inside the class definition.

Comment: can you illustrate what you're looking for in other language? Because my understanding of your question makes no sense in an object oriented language...

Comment: What do you want to be returned when there are multiple pointers to the same object?  I don't think what you are looking for is really possible.

Comment: Well, what I'm looking for is basically a method to be able to reach an object that an object of a class is an attribute of from within the custom class. Let me say it like this - I can't define the 'parent' class - it's hard-coded in a game engine I'm using. So, class A is already defined, and can handle attributes like a normal object. Class B is a custom class - I create an object from Class B and put it into an attribute of Class A. So, parentobj.objb = ClassB(). Now, is there any way for objb to tell what parentobj is?

Answer (score 10):

(I know this is an old question but since it's unanswered...)
You could try messing with the [garbage collector](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html). Was going to suggest looking at the module level objects but some quick code experimentation gave this: Try the [`gc.get_referrers(*objs)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#gc.get_referrers) function.

```
import gc

class Foo(object):
    """contains Bar"""
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.bar = None

class Bar(object):
    """wants to find its parents"""
    def __init__(self, something):
        self.spam = something

    def find_parents(self):
        return gc.get_referrers(self)
```

The results aren't straightforward so you'll have to apply your own logic for how determine which `f` is the one you're looking for. Notice the `'f': <__main__.Foo object at ...>` below:

```
>>> f = Foo(4)
>>> b = Bar('ham')
>>> f.bar = b
>>> b.find_parents()
[{'bar': <__main__.Bar object at 0x7f3ec5540f90>, 'val': 4}, <frame object at 0x238c200>,
{'b': <__main__.Bar object at 0x7f3ec5540f90>,
    'Bar': <class '__main__.Bar'>,
    'f': <__main__.Foo object at 0x7f3ec5540f10>,    # <-- these might be
                                          # the droids you're looking for
    '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>,
    '__package__': None, 'gc': <module 'gc' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__',
    'Foo': <class '__main__.Foo'>, '__doc__': None
}]
```

For bonus points, use [`gc.get_referents(*objs)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#gc.get_referents) on those to check if the same `b` is in their list.

Some notes/caveats:

- I think you should just pass the parent Foo object to Bar, either in `init` or another method. That's what I would do, instead of my suggestion above.
- [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10791613/1431750) points out some issues the garbage collector has when linking both ways - you're not currently doing that but if you do, fyi.

Answer (score 6):

you could do something like this:

```
class Object:
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if isinstance(value, Test):
            value.set_parent(self)
        self.__dict__[name] = value

class Test:
    def set_parent(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

o = Object()
o.test = Test()
assert o.test.parent is o
```

Comment: the problem with that is there is no way for `Test()` to react to being assiged to a name `test` on another object `o` other than for that object `o` to react to the assignment to `o.test` and for it to tell the assigned object `Test()`.

Answer (score 2):

well, I donno what exactly you are trying. but I have done something like this.

```
class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.parent = ''
        self.child = []
        self.name = name

    def setParent(self, parent):
        if isinstance(parent, tempNode):
            self.parent = parent.name
            parent.setChild(self.name)

    def setChild(self, child):
        self.child.append(child)

    def getParent(self):
        return self.parent

    def getChild(self):
        return self.child
```

and to make a parent you can say

```
n1 = Node('Father')
n2 = Node('Son')
n2.setParent('Father') # it will set n1 as parent and n2 as child at the same time.
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about inheritance? It's not very clear what you mean, but if you just want to do this:

```
class Test():
  def __init__(self,o):
    self.parent = o
  def other_method(self):
    do_something_with(self.parent)
```

It works perfectly.

**ed: This is not at all how you should do inheritance, if you want to do that. However, the way you describe your problem I think you want to create a tree-like structure of objects, not have classes inherit properties from each other.

Comment: He didn't refer to his code as inheritance. He just showed that he (the OP) could just access `o` via `self.parent` from within the object, because that's what he asked for, most likely.

Comment: What phant0m said. The way he's describing his need as "the object that a custom object is 'inside' of," I don't think inheritance is what he wants.

Comment: No, like kasnero and phant0m said, my question doesn't have to do anything with inheritance, but rather an issue of getting an object from within another object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want inheritable objects do it properly

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

class Bobcat(Test):
    def __init__(self):
        Test.__init__(self)
        self.b = 4
```

Comment: They're not inheritable at all - the two classes have nothing to do with each other. The point is just to get the object that an object of a class is stored in - basically, given objectA.obj = ObjectB(), is there a way to get objectA from within ObjectB's code, like a __owner__ property or something like that? Or do I have to do it myself?

Comment: @SolarLune: you can reference an object a gazillion times, e.g. `a = b = c = obj`. Which of those three would .owner return? You DO have `gc.get_referrers(*objs)` though which (maybe) does what you want. Edit: oops, this is OLD. Disregard.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
class Alpha:
def __init__(self):
    self.a = None

def start(self):
    self.get_a()
    self.print()
    self.SubBravo(self).multiply()
    self.print()
    self.SubAlpha(self).add_two()
    self.print()

def get_a(self):
    self.a = int(input("Enter an integer: >>> "))

def print(self):
    print("a: ", self.a)

class SubAlpha:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    def add_two(self):
        print("hello add_two")
        self.parent.a += 2
        self.parent.print()
        self.add_five()

    def add_five(self):
        print("hello add_five")
        self.parent.a += 5

class SubBravo:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    def multiply(self):
        print("hello multiply")
        self.parent.a *= 10


Alpha().start()
```