# Getting container/parent object from within contained object

Tags: python, class, object, containers

In Python, is it possible to get the object, say `Foo`, that contains another object, `Bar`, from within `Bar` itself?  Here is an example of what I mean:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = Bar()
        self.text = "Hello World"

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # I want to access the properties of the container object
        self.newText = foo.text

foo = Foo()
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You've got a typo; in `Foo.__init__`, `self.bar = Foo()` should be `self.bar = Bar()`. Otherwise you've got an infinite loop (in order to create a Foo, you first have to create a Foo).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Pass a reference to the Bar object, like so:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = "Hello World"  # has to be created first, so Bar.__init__ can reference it
        self.bar = Bar(self)

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.newText = parent.text

foo = Foo()
```

**Edit:** as pointed out by @thomleo, this can cause problems with garbage collection. The suggested solution is laid out at http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/06/12/safely-using-destructors-in-python/ and looks like

```
import weakref

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = "Hello World"
        self.bar = Bar(self)

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = weakref.ref(parent)    # <= garbage-collector safe!
        self.newText = parent.text

foo = Foo()
```

Comment: Thanks, this works.  The only problem I can see with that is, when I am trying to access many objects up, I will be making a call to `parent.parent.parent.etc`.  Is there a neater way of doing this?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, there is also a major issue with that. When you try to do ``del foo`` it won't necessarily destroy it as a reference to it still exists in the ``.parent`` attribute of the ``Bar`` it contains...

Comment: @MichaelMcClenaghan, in that case, you can just iterate up a number of times instead of manually spelling it out. Of course, that depends on the structure...

Comment: Don't you need to call the weak reference object? self.newText = self.parent().text

Comment: My mistake, answer is using parent.text (the object) not self.parent.text (the weakref)

Answer (score 5):

> is it possible to get the object, say Foo, that contains another object, Bar, from within Bar itself?

Not "automatically", because the language isn't built like that, and in particular, the language is built such that there is no way to guarantee that Foo exists.

That said, you can always do it explicitly. Attributes, like every other identifier in Python, are just names, not storage space for data; so nothing prevents you from letting the Bar instance have a manually assigned `foo` attribute that is a Foo instance, and vice-versa at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible. Even without passing the container reference on object creation, i.e. if your object is a class attribute.
Your object needs to implement the descriptor protocol (have a `__get__()`):

```
class ChildName(SimpleNamespace):                                                         

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        # instance is our parent
        return f'I am {self.name}, my parent is {instance.name}.'


class ChildDiff(SimpleNamespace):

    @property
    def diff(self):
        return self.born - self.parent.born

    def age_diff(self):
        return f'I am {self.diff} years older than {self.parent.name}.'

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        self.parent = instance  # XXX: weakref?
        return self  # expose object to be able call age_diff() etc.


class Parent(SimpleNamespace):

    child_name = ChildName(name='Bar')
    child_diff = ChildDiff(born=42)


parent = Parent(name='Foo', born=23)
print(parent.child_name)             # ... I am Bar, my parent is Foo.
print(parent.child_diff.age_diff())  # ... I am 19 years older than Foo.
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

**the parent**:

```
import child

obj_1  = 25             # an object that both parent and child can access

def startup():          # any startup function
    global obj_1
    child.ref( obj_1 )  # send the shared object to the child
    ...
```

**the child**:

```
obj_1 = 0               # initual value will be overwritten

def ref(shared_obj):    # receive a reference to the shared object
    global  obj_1       # shared object is global in the child, optional
    obj_1 = shared_obj  # set obj_1 in the child to be obj_1 in the parent
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with inspect

```py
import inspect

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = "Hello World"
        self.bar = Bar()

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        parentFrameInfo = inspect.stack()[1]
        parentLocalContext = parentFrameInfo.frame.f_locals
        # in parent context (__init__ of Foo) object instance is in variable 'self'
        foo = parentLocalContext["self"]
        self.newText = foo.text #This is what I want to do, 
                                #access the properties of the container object

foo = Foo()
print(foo.text)
print(foo.bar.newText)
```

but you need to declare `self.text` before `self.bar` in your constructor. If you do not, self.text is not defined when `Bar()` is called

Anyway, this should be done only if you have real specific constraint (for backward compatibility where `Foo` constructor API couldn't be change for example). Adding in `Bar` constructor `Foo` instance is a better solution.

Answer (score -3):

What about using inheritance:

```
class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.newText = self.text

class Foo(Bar):
    def __init__(self):
        self.txt = 'Hello World'
        Bar.__init__(self)

foo = Foo()
print foo.newText
```