# Change text of QLineEdit from another class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have 2 classes : MainWindow() and ModelSelection().

I would like to access a `QLineEdit` which is declared in MainWindow() from ModelSelection() in order to change the text of the `QLineEdit` thanks to the method `setText()`.

**mainWindow.py**

```
from modelSelection import ModelSelection

def __init__(self, workingDir, filename, mode, tabAnalysis, parent=None):
    super(MainWindow,self).__init__(parent)
    self.fileLine = QLineEdit()
```

**modelSelection.py**

```
import mainWindow    

def openModelDialog(self):
    self.filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File",filePath,"(*.txt)")

    if self.filename:
        mainWindow.fileLine.setText(self.filename[0])
    return self.filename
```

It returns : `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fileLine'`

Comment: I'll suggest reading this: [Modules, Classes, and Objects](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex40.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing class and module.
The module `mainWindow.py` contain a class `MainWindow`. The attribute `fileLine` belongs to the class, not the module.

Anyway, you shouldn't have to import `mainWindow` in `modelSelection.py`.
You're already importing `modelSection` in `mainWindow.py`, so my guess is
that `mainWindow` is the parent of `modelSelection`.
In this case, you can check this question: [Getting container/parent object from within python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10791588/getting-container-parent-object-from-within-python)

Answer (score 0):

I presume the rest of your code is working and you have only provided minimal information. Add a 'self' in this line.

```
self.mainWindow.fileLine.setText(self.filename[0])
```