# Python Namespace (Property) of inherited methods

Tags: python, class, inheritance, properties

What I would like to do is access the inherited methods using a certain namespace, for example:

```python
class ExtraMeths(object):
    def specialmeth():
        pass

class MainClass(ExtraMeths):
    def standardmeth():
       pass
myclass = MainClass()
myclass.standardmeth()  #works
myclass.specialmeth()  #also works, but not ideal
```

Now ideally what I would like to do is run `myclass.ExtraMeths.specialmeth()` where the name `ExtraMeths` is not important, but it is in its own 'property' of the main class. Also important that the inherited class is inherited, i.e. the same `self` variables are available to it.

The reason is that there are a lot of methods and I would like to bring some order to them, so grouping similar ones together seems to make sense.

Comment: Then don't use *inheritance*, use *composition*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be done using composition:

```
class ExtraMeths(object):
    def __init__(self, main):
        self.main = main

    def specialmeth(self):
        # can use self.main here to access outer class variables

class MainClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.extra_meths = ExtraMeths(self)

    def standardmeth(self):
        pass

myclass = MainClass()
myclass.standardmeth()
myclass.extra_meths.specialmeth()
```

Comment: Very cool- thank you. Any way for it not to have to use self.main?

Comment: You don't need the `self.main` if `ExtraMeths` doesn't need to access anything on a `MainClass` instance to do it's work.

Comment: As stated in the question- it would be ideal if `ExtraMeths` acted like an inherited class of `MainClass`, i.e. shared the same self, but was access through the composition.

Comment: There is also a problem with garbage collection with this method as stated (and fixed) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10791613/2356861

Comment: @RexFuzzle that should only be an issue f you plan on implementing a `__del__` method, which you probably shouldn't anyway...

Comment: @RexFuzzle you could use a [mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful), but that doesn't solve your namespacing issue. Unfortunately I think you're going to have to choose between solving one problem or the other.